# Google Sheets: IMPORTHTML not fetching table 10

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been periodically updating my Finance profile with my dividend returns.
While the online Yields reported may not be 100% accurate, I still wish to pull the  Foward Annual Dividend Yield.

I previously had the following to pull the Yield from Yahoo:

```
=vlookup("Forward Annual Dividend Yield"&"*",IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics","table",10),2,0)
```

It appears now, `IMPORTHTML` is unable to pull table 10. Reports back to me `#REF`:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics","table",10)
```

Where as

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics","table",9)
```

has no problem reporting back the "Avg Vol (3month) - 1.92M" "Avg Vol (10 day) - 1.55M" and so on.

If there is no problem pulling table 10 from other sites, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative you can try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics", 
 "//td[@class='Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)']"), 51, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

works just fine on this side:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics", "table", 10)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/O/key-statistics", "table", 10), 2, 2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I appreciate the time that you have taken to show me what the intended output should be. When I past that exact, character or character string, I get "#REF!" - with the Error: Function INDEX parameter 2 value is 2. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-WJM1totBN9-3_MkFonKH80OijGcUmUcTEoxmcFgZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: looks like your sheet is somehow corrupted and corruption is transferred even if you make a copy of your sheet. try to take a copy of my sheet if it solves your issue because I kind of get it as I should: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UZp0.png sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v4a0uVMXZ3LCZZUS0cOrBUP7B2aX0zzPCsgwR_ChdfY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have viewed this sheet on multiple computers. I am on the latest Google Chrome update. 
https://imgur.com/a/UXuNZC3